# While loop is not displaying all values

Tags: php, while-loop

I am having this weird problem. 
There are seven admins: darth, jane, luke, najin, root, sam and sydney.

CODE:

```
    <table>
          <tr>
            <th style="text-align: left; width: 200px;">Username</th>
            <th colspan="2" style="text-align: left;">Action</th>
          </tr>
        <?php 

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM admins ORDER BY Admin_Username ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
            $admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            while($admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo ($admin["Admin_Username"]); ?></td>
            <td><a href="edit_admin.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($admin["id"]); ?>">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="delete_admin.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($admin["id"]); ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this admin?');">Delete</a></td>
          </tr>
        <?php     
} 
?>
</table>
```

If I use `ASC` order, the first admin, darth is not displayed in the loop and if I use `DESC` order, the last admin, sydney doesn't show up.
What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the first `$admin =` line.

Your loop will fetch all of them; you don't need to fetch the first one separately (and if fact by doing so are skipping it, because your loop immediately fetches the second before the first one could be written out).

Answer (score 3):

remove this line

```
 $admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);//You already fetching the first result here
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a redundant call to `$admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` before the `while` loop which will cause you to skip the first row of the result. Just remove it and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?php 

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM admins ORDER BY Admin_Username ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);    
            while($admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo ($admin["Admin_Username"]); ?></td>
            <td><a href="edit_admin.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($admin["id"]); ?>">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="delete_admin.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($admin["id"]); ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this admin?');">Delete</a></td>
          </tr>
    <?php     
    } 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

This must be in while loop So you can descard/remove old value above while